# Tweaking the SQL for a jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

I have a jQuery autocomplete widget on my page that populates a search bar with client names in my database. However, it's not acting as I expected.

Here's the SQL I'm using to fetch the names from the database:

```
SELECT First, Last, Middle 
FROM Clients
WHERE First + ' ' + Last like ?
```

and then I bind the search term to the parameter.

The problem I have though is the results I'm getting when the search bar is populated are pretty off. For example, if I type in 'Shirley', I see names like Deborah Smith (hypothetical). So, I think the problem lies with my query, but I don't really know how to tweak it to make find the results I want (in this case, all Shirleys).

Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you heard anything about SQL injection?

Comment: Of course. That's why I'm binding the parameter.

Comment: If you pass 'Shirley' and get 'Deborah Smith' with this query then there is something wrong that needs to be FIXED not tweaked.

Comment: like I said, Deborah Smith is a hypothetical. I can't use real names here, I only meant to demonstrate that the results are unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT First, Last, Middle 
FROM Clients
WHERE concat(First,' ',Last) like concat('%', ?, '%')
```

The most important difference is that I am passing the % before and after the search term to enable searching for the term anywhere within the first and last names. Additionally, I am using concat to combine the strings together.

I dont have a MySQL to access with me here and I could not test it but this should work. I use it for autocomplete likewise.

Comment: Sorry somnath, this doesn't work either. I still get the same results,

Comment: Technically you cant get the same results. If you had sent the '%' earlier with the string, then passing it again with my solution will generate '%%shirley%%' which will not populate the result list. Since you say there is no difference in the resultset then could it be you are connecting to the wrong database on the AJAX script than the one you are testing the results with? Just guessing, but I have seen these silly issues kill time even for experienced hands.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you are sending the request to the DB for every character typed, and are receiving results for one or some of the characters that end up matching.

Can you add debugging code so that you can tell which request resulted in what data back from the DB?

If I was debugging it, I would like to have returned back to me:

1. The request param 'Shirley'
2. The SQL query if I am changing it in any way based on the data (doesn't look like you are, yay params!)
3. All of the data

Then I would update my code so that in addition to giving the data back, I also receive the above.  Then you can manually hit the autocomplete url/service that you have created and double check that you receive back the data that you expect for a manual query.

If this looks good, then I would add a spot on my page to show how many times I have called the autocomplete service, and a spot to show what data the autocomplete service says that I called it with.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are reading  `First, Last, Middle` but the where clause only uses `First,Last`.

It could be the case that the string that's displayed is derived from `Middle` whereas the where clause filters based on `First,Last` values.

Comment: That was a good idea, but after matching the Select clause to the Where clause, I still have the same problem.